# Apache webserver - Mod status

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, web-server

Heey all,
I have a question regarding the Mod Status module of Apache.

https://www.apache.org/server-status

As you guys can see there is a line: `Total accesses` and a value after it.
Is it possible to set restrictions of what to count and what not?
For example I've written a program which get this server-status info every 5 seconds. The program will access the page so total accesses will be +1 extra.
As the program is running on the specific server is it possible to restrict it from counting for calls coming from localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible via configuration. I'd recommend just having a counter in your program counting the number of requests it has made, and subtract this from the total.

You can see the documentation for mod_status here; https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html
As you can see, the only extra option you have is turning ExtendedStatus on.

You might be able to do it if you modify the mod, and recompile it.

Comment: Counter will be easy solution then (yet ugly) ah well